# Insert row with specific value above first occurrence of partial string

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple sheets in a workbook. For some sheets I want to find a partial string in column A, for example "BAG", and insert a row above first occurrence with value "BAGBEE".

Also, can I apply this to multiple partial strings in column A?
For example
if "BAG" found, the above row inserted should be "BAGBEE".
if "CAT" found, the above row inserted should be "CATLINE".

This inserts a row at the bottom but I am looking for code which inserts a row above the first occurrence of partial string.

```vb
Sub try()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = 1
    Dim lRowLast As Long
    Dim bFound As Boolean
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Requires Client Review")
        lRowLast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Do
            Set c = .Range("A" & lRow)
            If c.Value Like "*BAG*" Then
                bFound = True
            ElseIf bFound Then
                bFound = False
                If c.Value <> "BAGBEE" Then
                    c.EntireRow.Insert
                    lRowLast = lRowLast + 1
                    c.Offset(-1, 0).Value = "BAGBEE"
                    c.Offset(-1, 0).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                End If
            End If
            lRow = lRow + 1
        Loop While lRow <= lRowLast + 1
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You could have an array of search terms and loop through them. Using Find would be more efficient than looping through every row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code here. I'm used to using Cells as reference.
I've tested it and works as I expected.

Edited to add worksheets loop.

```
Private Sub Try_it()
Dim LongRow     As Long
Dim Lastrow     As Long
Dim ArryText    As Variant
Dim WSheet      As Worksheet

For Each WSheet In Worksheets
    WSheet.Select
    Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For LongRow = Lastrow To 2 Step -1
        For Each ArryText In Array("*BAG*", "*CAT*") ' you can add your search word here
            If Cells(LongRow, 1) Like ArryText And Cells(LongRow - 1, 1) Like ArryText Then
                'do something
            ElseIf Cells(LongRow, 1) Like ArryText Then
                Select Case ArryText
                    Case "*BAG*" ' for each matched case you can assign it to whatever name you want
                        Rows(LongRow).Insert
                        Cells(LongRow, 1).Value = "BAGBEE"  'BAGBEE
                        Cells(LongRow, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                    Case "*CAT*" ' for each matched case you can assign it to whatever name you want
                        Rows(LongRow).Insert
                        Cells(LongRow, 1).Value = "CATLINE" 'CATLINE
                        Cells(LongRow, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                End Select
            End If
        Next
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks and it worked. If possible can we add a code to it so that it loops through specified worksheets in a workbook?